# How can I put the cursor behind the text in editable cell in object list view control?

Tags: cursor, objectlistview

The cursor has been put behind the text by the following code when the "CellEditStarting" event triggered:

```
((IntUpDown)e.Control).Select(e.Control.Text.Length, 0);
```

[cursor behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2eaL.png)

but after the user clicks on the up-arrow in the cell control, the cursor was put in front of the text again.

[cursor in front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJpWW.png)

Is there any event triggered when user click on the up-arrow in the cell control? So that the cursor can be put behind the text again.

Comment: You probably would have to Sub-Class the NumericUpDown Control and then use it as a custom cell editor for the OLV.

Comment: Hmm, are you using the `Aspect` property or the `AspectGetter` and `AspectSetter` delegates? Maybe its enough to set the cursor in the `AspectSetter`.